# Fiddling type inference on number conversion

Tags: f#, type-inference

I've got a function which takes an input of type

```
('a * (float * 'b * float)) list
```

Where I'd obviously like to avoid having to explicitly include the type.

The problem is that I convert the second float to decimal, using the decimal function.

```
let v2 (_,(_,_,v)) = decimal v
```

So type inference defaults to seeing this:

```
('a * (float * 'b * int)) list
```

Is there anything clever I can do to avoid having to explicitly include the type signature of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there something wrong with doing it like this?

```
let v2 (_,(_,_,v:float)) = decimal v
```

Comment: No. I had a brain fart and tried `let v2 (_,(_,_,float:v)) = decimal v`, then gave up and came here, must be the lack of sleep. Thanks.